# Can any one tell me how to add scrollbar to sprite in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on flash player, i want to add list of sprites on the player,(approx:10) but i don't have that much of space to do that, so to overcome this problem i just want to add scroll bar to it.Can any one tell me how to add scroll bar to sprite?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Scroller component: [Scroller API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html)

You'll want to put the Sprites in a Group, which implements the IViewport interface required by Scroller.

Here's a quick example I pulled from an old test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           applicationComplete="run()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            function run():void
            {
                var s1:Sprite = new Sprite();
                var s2:Sprite = new Sprite();

                s1.x = 100;
                s1.y = 100;
                s1.graphics.beginFill(0x00cc55);
                s1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                s1.graphics.endFill();

                s2.x = 300;
                s2.y = 300;
                s2.graphics.beginFill(0x4400dd);
                s2.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
                s2.graphics.endFill();

                display.addChild(s1);
                display.addChild(s2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Scroller id="theScroller" width="200" height="200">
        <s:Group id="theGroup">
            <s:SpriteVisualElement id="display" width="500" height="500"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: The question wasn't tagged Flex, so not sure if this will be helpful.

Comment: I'd bet he is not using Flex... That is a beginner's question.

Answer (score 0):

before I used this custom scrollbar.it's good option for your project.
you can find source file in [this url](http://theflashconnection.com/sites/default/files/Jody%20Hall/vertical_scrollbar_final.zip)